# When I search for debian-installer, how do I filter out questions about installing * on Debian?

Tags: support, tags, search

firstly there does not appear to be a d-i tag or equivalent so I am operating under the assumption that all questions about the debian installer will be tagged [debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian) but when I search for "[debian] installer" the signal to noise ratio is atrocious due to automatic inclusion of related words. I am not interested in in *installing* mplayer, how to *install* vlc, or broken wine *installation*.

Is there a way to tune my search?

Comment: I usually break out and go to Google search for this type of thing, or add in user names such as user:gilles or myself or whomever, but for your search you'd be correct that the noise is bad.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian+installer You can search for multiple tags.

Comment: I think having a `debian-installer` tag would be reasonable.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I found one question that would use it and I have another to add.

Comment: @hildred I assume you don't have the rep to add it. I think I do, but Let's see what others say first.

Comment: @FaheemMitha apparently I do (it only needs 300).

Comment: Search for [tag:debian] [tag:system-installation] (or [tag:debian] [tag:install] for older posts, but we're phasing out the [tag:install] tag).

Answer (score 2):

We use the [system-installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) tag for installing systems. Therefore, use `[debian] [system-installation]` as your search query, and that should get you relevant results.